# JavaScript Starter Framework Errors

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn more about JavaScript and I am messing around with... stuff. Could someone tell me why I am getting errors in my script please.

```
// Effects object
var effects = {
 // Display an object
 show : function(obj) {
  obj.style.display = 'block';
 },
 // Hide an object
 hide : function(obj) {
  obj.style.display = 'hide'; 
 },
 // Toggle
 toggle : function(obj) {
  if (obj instanceof Array) {
   alert('array');
  } else {
   alert('single'); 
  }
 }
}

// Selector Class
var s = {
 id : function(name) {
  return document.getElementById(name);
 },
 class : function(name) {
  node = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var a = [];
  var re = new RegExp('\\b' + classname + '\\b');
  var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
   if(re.test(els[i].className))
    a.push(els[i]);
  return a;
 }
}

window.onload = function() {
 s.id('toggle-content').onClick(function() {
  effects.toggle(s.class('hidden-content'));
 });
}
```

I get the following errors:

When page loads:

> Error: s.id("toggle-content").onClick
>   is not a function Source File:
>   http://localhost/cms/web/js/admin.js
>   Line: 40

On a slight tangent. Is there a standardised way to get a class from the dom?

Solved.

**onclick= instead of onClick()**

Answer (score 0):

Event names in Javascript don't follow the camelCase style of properties and methods.  They're all lower case.  Change `onClick` to `onclick` and you should be good to go.

On your slight tangent, some browsers already support [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) (which I think is what you're asking for).  There are [alternatives](http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/) for browsers that don't support it.